# Cannot connect to Podman container outside of host machine

Tags: docker, networking, containers, grafana, podman

I have been trying to create a Grafana container on my Tumbleweed server using Podman. I used `NetworkManager` instead of `wickedd` on this server. I of course published port 3000 when I ran the container:

> sudo podman run -d -p 3000:3000 --name=grafana_hub -v grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana grafana/grafana

and whitelisted the port in firewalld:

> sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3000/tcp

but no dice.

I can access the web server with `curl http://localhost:3000` on the host or even `curl http://<host LAN IP>:3000` from the host, however if I run the latter on another machine on the LAN, it times out. I am at a loss here. Is there something different about Podman networking from Docker I am missing?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? My question exactly...